# Transfer attributes from inner polygons to surrounding polygons on other layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, fields-attributes, merge

I have a vector polygon grid and multipart building polygons (one selected for demonstration) already cut to grid size.

[image]

How do I get all the attribute data from the buildings into the grid layer?

I'm sure the solution is quite simple and must be part of basic vector geoprocessing tools, but at the moment I don't find it.

Comment: Use a spatial join https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/performing_spatial_joins.html

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for. In the previous steps I used many geoprocessing tools manipulating vector geometries, so I was looking in vain for a solution within "Vector" > "Geoprocessing Tools". Of course, no geometry has to be changed in this case.